# How to correctly display text from db which has HTML formatting and text formatting

Tags: php, html

I have text in db which looks like this:

```
<p>
blah blah

blah
</p>
```

When I get the text out of db and display it, I am able to get the `<p></p>` to make the paragraph space, but the paragraph between the lines of blah does not show up.

When I try to make it work together, I end up with new lines after the natural new line from pressing the enter, and new line from `<p>` so I end up with way too much space between paragraphs.

Is there a way to make sure both ways of formatting work together nicely?

Comment: You have to replace newlines (`\n`) with `<br>` tags before displaying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
echo nl2br($db_string);
```

Comment: While this is technically correct and may produce the desired result, it appears the OP is simply misusing the paragraph tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the correct way to go about this is fixing the HTML.  This doesn't seem like a PHP issue.  You say you want to display space between the first line `blah blah` and the second line `blah`.  I would rewrite it to be:

```
<p>
    blah blah
</p>
<p>
    blah
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this css rule

```
p {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

If you do it this way, then you won't need to do any transformation of the string itself.